# Is there a better way to manage has_many relationship with jsonb in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form, jsonb, has-many

Considering Students who can study various things, I'm storing those in a jsonb column referencing a Studies table. Indexing the studies isn't really important (for now) and I prefer to avoid a relationship table.

Therefore: `add_column :students, :studies, :jsonb, default: []`

And in my simple form (in slim):

```rb
= simple_form_for @student do |f|
  = f.input :studies, as: :check_boxes, collection: Study.all, label_method: :name
```

This works *stupendously* well considering the brevity and the simplicity of it. Except for one small detail: the form doesn't check previously saved studies as their IDs are stored as strings in the jsonb array `["", "2", "12"]` and the form apparently requires integers.

I resorted to add a studies' value function in the Student model, but it seems sooo overkill (also the `.reject(&:zero?)` to remove the empty array value):

```rb
def studies=(array)
  # transform strings to integers and remove leading empty value
  super(array.map(&:to_i).reject(&:zero?))
end
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I would say the better way is just using the relationship table. Overriding the assignment method on a model is generally not the right approach.

JSONB is nice, gives flexibility, and can be even queried nicely, but unless you have a really strong reason to go with it in this case, you should probably stick to `has_many :through...` association.

Either way, depending on how you wired everything, maybe instead of overriding the assignment method you would be better by putting your logic in action filters or somewhere where you do model validation...

Comment: It's not a _strong_ reason, it's just that the relationship is not needed, so why bloat the db? I took the suggestion of putting it in a custom `validate` method (that I already had). I didn't know you could (or should) do that. Thanks